# Naive Bayes Classification for Categorical Data

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, bayesian-networks, categorical-data

I am new to statistics and data mining. I followed the example [here](http://joshwalters.github.io/2012/11/27/naive-bayes-classification-in-r.html), which worked perfect. Now I want to apply this method to my dataset which, however, consists of categorical data only.

R gives the following error:

```
Error in train.default(x, y, "nb", trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",  :
wrong model type for regression
```

My question is: what sort of transformations should I make in order to apply that method on my categorical set of data?

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
bbb <- data.frame(x=c("Cleveland", "London", "London", "Ashburn"),y= c("USA", "GBR", "GBR", "USA"))
x = bbb$x
y = bbb$y
model = train(x,y,'nb',trControl=trainControl(method='cv',number=1))
model
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: What are you doing? Please provide some code!

Comment: ok guys, I have updated the question so as to show you what I have done so far.

Comment: This appears to work: `model = train(bbb$x,bbb$y,'nb',trControl=trainControl(number=1))`. Maybe `method='cv'` is not a good fit for this toy problem?

Answer (score 1):

because labels of your dataset are in numeric format, R decide to use regression instead of classification.

change labels of data set to characters instead of numbers. so R will not confuse.